# re.search python regexpr

Tags: python, regex

for my assignment I need to search through a program and print out how many pages each user has printed.

```
date: 2012-11-25
printer on time:  0800 
23.96.82.161 user: pei printer: core 2 pages: 2 code: r n t h p r
28.104.177.80 user: isaac printer: poster pages: 4 code: p h
printer error:  out of paper  time: 1343
180.186.109.129 user: luis printer: core 2 pages: 2 code: k n h
194.96.54.184 user: isaac printer: sally pages: 6 code: p k r p f
122.230.32.236 user: luis printer: hill 3 pages: 8 code: n h n k q
printer off time: 2201
```

is an example of what the program will contain,

```
for stringprint in logfile:
        userRegex = re.search('(\suser:\s)(.+?)(\sprinter:\s)', stringprint)
        if userRegex:
            userString = userRegex.group(2)
            numpages = int(re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)', stringprint).group(2))

            if userString not in users:
                user[userString] = numpages
            else:
                user[userString] += numpages
```

my problem is the re.search isn't working properly, I believe the expression to be correct but it is clearly not. I know that `\s` matches white spaces, also the `.+?` is the lazy version of matching the preceding token. once I find a match i use the the `user.Regex.group(2)` to set it to the "username". from there I then want to search for the number of pages and code (to make sure correct match) and then proceed to print it. I know that this regex is not working but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

when I run the program via module i get :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 45, in <module>
    log2hist("log")  # version 2.
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 29, in log2hist
    numpages = int(re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)',stringprint).group(2))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: my error is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 45, in <module>
    log2hist("log")  # version 2.
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 29, in log2hist
    numpages = int(re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)',stringprint).group(2))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` @sln

Comment: how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm unsure, like I said I am extremely new to python and I am just trying to work through this. When I went to regexpr.com I was able to get a match for the first `re.search()` but then when I attempted to use the second regex i got nothing. I think the first okay but not the second with the `int()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110193/discussion-between-bkennedy-and-sln).

Comment: it still does not work for me, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 46, in <module>
    log2hist("log")  # version 2.
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 31, in log2hist
    numpages = int(pagesmatch.group(2))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: If using an intermediate like `stringnumpages = pagesmatch.group(2)` and then `numpages = int(stringnumpages)` then the problem is in the `int() ` If you get the error on `stringnumpages` then you should have gotten it on `userString = userRegex.group(2)`

Comment: do you have any clue how to fix that? I am so confused and have been working on the problem all day

Comment: Did you try that last thing? Actually, you'd need someone who knows Python. Also, search this site for `Python regex` to get some usage examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

I recommend switching up your Regex so it'll be a bit more flexible. This regex will do the following:

- capture the username
- capture the number of prints
- allow the user and pages to appear in any order. This becomes handy if you wanted to start capturing other data

**The Regex**

```
^(?=.*?user:\s+(.*?)\s)(?=.*?pages:\s+(.*?)\s).*?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Explained**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    user:                    'user:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    pages:                   'pages:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
```

## Examples

**Online Demo of Regex**

http://fiddle.re/13chna

**Sample Python Code**

https://repl.it/CJdF/0

```
import re

SampleString = '''date: 2012-11-25
printer on time:  0800 
23.96.82.161 user: pei printer: core 2 pages: 2 code: r n t h p r
28.104.177.80 user: isaac printer: poster pages: 4 code: p h
printer error:  out of paper  time: 1343
180.186.109.129 user: luis printer: core 2 pages: 2 code: k n h
194.96.54.184 user: isaac printer: sally pages: 6 code: p k r p f
122.230.32.236 user: luis printer: hill 3 pages: 8 code: n h n k q
printer off time: 2201'''
print (SampleString)

## Here re.findall()
Regex=re.compile(r'^(?=.*?user:\s+(.*?)\s)(?=.*?pages:\s+(.*?)\s).*?$',re.MULTILINE)
Matches = Regex.findall( SampleString) 
Count = 0
for Match in Matches:
    # do something with each found email string
    print("[" + str(Count) + "][0] = " + Match[0])
    print("[" + str(Count) + "][1] = " + Match[1])
    print("")
    Count = Count + 1
```

**Sample Output**

```
[0][0] = pei
[0][1] = 2

[1][0] = isaac
[1][1] = 4

[2][0] = luis
[2][1] = 2

[3][0] = isaac
[3][1] = 6

[4][0] = luis
[4][1] = 8
```

Comment: you mean printer as opposed to pages in this regex correct? or are you telling me to completely change both regex I am using to this?

Comment: @bkennedy, My suggestion is about flexibility. For example lets say you hard code the capture groups returned by your regex, then later decide that you'd like to collect something additional like IP address or printer name, you'd have have to go back and change all capture group numbers in your code. Whereas with these positive lookaheads like I'm using here you can assemble the capture groups in any order. So additional capture groups could simply be tacked on as additional lookaheads thereby preserving the capture group number sequence.